# Multivariable Calculus question (Integration)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is from James Stewart's Multivariable Calculus book, page 651 question 33. 
Find the area enclosed by the x-axis and the curve $x=1+e^t$, $y=t-t^2$.

The answer given has the following steps that I do not understand. It's supposed to be integration by parts. 
$$\int_0^1(t-t^2)e^tdt$$
$$=\int_0^1te^tdt-\int_0^1t^2e^tdt=\int_0^1te^tdt-[t^2e^t]_0^1+2\int_0^1te^tdt$$

My confusion is on $[t^2e^t]_0^1$, which is supposed to be $[f(x)g(x)]_a^b$ of the integration by part formula. Isn't $f(x)=t-t^2$ and $g(x)=1+e^t$?

Please advice.

Comment: can you explain more please ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be confused with just the standard integration by parts formula from calculus of a single variable. Below is what integration by parts tells us. $$\int _a^bu\,dv=uv\bigg\vert_a^b-\int_a^b v\,du$$
Here we have $$
\int_0^1\underbrace{\color{red}{t^2}}_u\,\underbrace{\color{blue}{e^t\,dt}}_{dv}
$$Since $dv=e^t\,dt$ we have $v=\int e^t\,dt=e^t$ hence $uv=t^2e^t$ as given.

---

In other words, the $f(t),g(t)$ come from our integrand:$$\int_a^b f(t)g'(t)dt=\left[f(t)g(t)\right]_a^b-\int f'(t)g(t)\,dt\\\int_a^b t^2e^t\,dt=[t^2e^t]_0^1-\int 2te^t\,dt$$Here, you have $f(t)=t^2,g'(t)=e^t$ and therefore $f'(t)=2t,g(t)=e^t$, not the unrelated functions $t-t^2,1+e^t$